# Angular list with generic component as list item

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-ngfor

Suppose I have a "ParentComponent" that has a list of items (let's say taken as an input) and needs to render the elements in the list. I need this parent component to be reusable however and one of the customizations it would support would be choosing the template (or component) it uses for rendering the list items. The component used for the child list items could be anything as long as it can render the list item given to it as an input (the template can correctly reference properties of the item). This is possible in frameworks such as React, so my question would be if it is possible as well in Angular and how one would do it?

I imagine the parent component taking the custom component as an input, along with the items

```
@Input()
items: Array<ItemType>;

@Input()
componentForRenderingStuff: ?;
```

And the template being something like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- ...stuff -->
  <div class="list-item" *ngFor="let i of items">
    <component-for-rendering-stuff [item]="i"></component-for-rendering-stuff>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which would mean that using the parent component in another template would be like

```
<app-parent-component [items]="items" [componentForRenderingStuff]="SomeComponent"></app-parent-component>
```

Is something like this possible? I looked at `ng-content` but I couldn't make it work with `*ngFor`.

Comment: I think this is too complicated an approach. It could be easier.
That component object pass to a child, this is a anti-pattern.
Define a component what you import into your module. And this component can be reuse anywhere. If you pass data to parent there exists a @Output annotation. Did you think of this?

Comment: If I was faced with this problem I would use ng-switch to load the correct component and simply have one child component that would hold the other components to be switched

Comment: @OwenKelvin yeah, I did this once in my app already and I'm kind of worried of those bindings being active all the time, waiting for changes in the input. Besides that the idea is that this list is might be used once let's say in a search bar dropdown, at another time in some completely other place, etc. with the goal is it being a light dependency for the different angular modules within the app.

Comment: @Numichi I'm at a loss, not sure I understand the "@Output" part within this context, as for this being an antipattern it is used heavily in React and with great success.

Comment: @Vee6 It may work there, but not really here. Approach thinking is different. It is more similar angular to server backend logic. Can you share more code about related components and modules?

Comment: there are two options that come to mind, one is using the template based solution mentioned by @OwenKelvin. the other is dynamic component loading. both have their pros and cons. however, if performance is a real concern for you, and you are looking to avoid the change detection that having so many if's in your template may cause, then you are left with dynamic component loading.

Comment: @Edward dynamic component loading was what I was looking for, I will update the question with this info

Answer (score 0):

As Edward suggested in his comment the behavior can be achieved using dynamic component loading.

I found a few third party libraries on npm which solved that and due to time and simplicity I used the one which had the most appealing user statistics: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component

In short a generic list component would look like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ndc-dynamic
        [ndcDynamicComponent]="listItemComponent"
        [ndcDynamicInputs]="{ input: item.data }"
      ></ndc-dynamic>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['...'],
})
export class ClickableVerticalListComponent {
  @Input()
  listItemComponent: any;

  @Input()
  items: Array<any>;

  constructor() {}
}
```

If we want to use the list with a specific custom component for a list item we would do it in this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: `
    <app-list 
      [items]="items" 
      [listItemComponent]="ExampleComponent"
    ></app-list>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['...'],
})
export class ParentComponent {
  ExampleComponent = ExampleComponent;

  items: [{ data: ... }, { data: ... }];

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: glad to hear you found a solution. just as an FYI for future use, angular native has documentation on dynamic component loading [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). good luck.